# Doubt on power generation by hydraliuc turbine

Tags: power-engineering

What happened to the final power generation if  the hydraliuc turbine rotates discontinously for example  if a turbine runner rotates with 2000 rpm for 2 minutes and stop rotating for 4 seconds and again rotates for a minute and this cycle continues.. And then what is the difference  between  final power generated by normal hydraliuc  turbine and this discontinous turbine..

Comment: What do you mean? Obviously, the power output from the discontinuous turbine is discontinuous. What else can you possibly say about it?

Comment: He probably wants some average for the discontinuous power output and compare it to the power of the normal turbine.

Comment: Yes absolutely i need average of the discontinuous power output and compare to the power of normal turbine

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider the system as a whole any rotating turbine has a certain amount of angular momentum so it is not just going to stop dead and come back up to speed in in a few seconds without some substantial forces involved. 2000 rpm to 0 to 2000 rpm in 4 seconds is fairly substantial acceleration for anything.

In the case of AC power distributed to a grid it is important that the angular speed of all the generators is synchronised to ensure a stable frequency so bringing individual generators on and off line needs to be done carefully and in response to the overall load on the system. With this in mind intermittent running of a generator could well cause problems downstream with power management.